# Creating multiple users or single user by once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just tried to create a function which allows me to create mulitple users at once but i have two errors, i cannot find a solution for them:
here is my controller

```
def create_multiple
    @staff = Employee.find(params[:employee_ids])
    @staff.each do |staff|
      staff = User.create do |user|
        user.email = 'employee"#{staff.id}"@hu.com'
        user.password = '12345678'
        user.password_confirmation = '12345678'
        user.user_type = 'employee'
      end
    end
    redirect_to staff_path
  end

  def new_multiple
    @staff = Employee.find(params[:employee_ids])
  end
```

the view (after selecting the employees with a checkbox):

```
<h5>Create Multiple Users</h5>

<%= form_tag create_multiple_employees_path, method: :post do %>
    <ul>
      <% @staff.each do |employee| %>
          <li>
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'employee_ids[]', employee.id %>
            <%= employee.full_name %>
          </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Creating User(s)" %>
    <% end %>
```

the two problems are:

1- it creates only one user

2- the email not take the id of the employee it submitted as `employee"#{staff.id}"@hu.com`

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: Broad question, but maybe this will help - http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised

Comment: @phoet why abroad ? all i am asking for is how to create users ( from the index of employees by choosing one employee or more at once

Comment: @Dexter is also not properly explained, no examples, no code, nothing.

Comment: @phoet just updated my question after trying to create it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is by using double qoutes in here:

```
"employee#{staff.id}@hu.com"
```

this solved my two problems above

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a checkbox to add a single employee to the user model.When you check the checkbox, maybe random username and password will be send to the employee email?

AND you are not asking programming question but something that 'is achiveable or not'

Comment: what i want to acheive is how to create accounts for an employee or all employees at once , i am looking for how to make it

Comment: You could make it easier and use your command line if your app is hosted with Heroku with `Heroku run rails console`

Comment: @Justin i am not talking about the console here! i am talking about feature which will be used by an admin..

Comment: This might not be what you're looking for, but check it out any and maybe it'll help lead to the right answer. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-administrative_users. It's having an Admin user destroy users all on one page.

Comment: @Justin I know how to restrict the actions ,my question again is :
" if you have an employee model and in the view you have a list of employees , how could i add them as users into my user model by selecting one or more employee by once , (the two models are not the same attributes)

Comment: Ohhhhhh I don't know. Sorry. Good luck though

Comment: @Nich i have updated my question with a code